# Is it possible to set format for the number field without Format Editor?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm using the Crystal reports in my current project. (VS2010,C#, WinForms)
I want to set a  format for the number field from  the code (in  code i want to determine current culture (CultureInfo) and use specific separator of this culture for my fields)
Or Maybe someone know the way how to use CultureInfo in FormatEditor ?

Comment: you can use formula too for formatting. what kind of format you wanna make?

Comment: for Europe use "," as decimal separator and for America use "."

Comment: ok fine, may i knw on what basis you determine its Europe or America ?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing formula for ***Decimal Seperator*** in ***Custom Style***.

See the Images for reference.
[image: Format Editor]
Then Select ***Cutomize*** to open Custom Style
[image: Custom Style]

On ***Decimal Seperator*** wirte an if else formula to show **,** or **.** as decimal seperator depends upon your requirement (Europe or American)

Try this and get back with your results.
Ready to help you.

Comment: I want to use something like that in formula:  CultureInfo userCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
string decimalSeparator = userCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
Maybe you know similar functions for Crystal reports?